# How to convert a string composed of html tags and text to html dom elements (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html

I have a Javascript programm with a string like that :

```
Les connecteurs enfichables DOIVENT être <\span class="barre"> équipé de<\/span>detrompeur.
```

And I would like to know how to convert this string in html dom an insert it in a div for exemple.

---

ANSWER :

Definitively I have found the solution to my question.
Just imagine you have a div tag like that :

```
<body>
    <div id="myId">my text or html content</div>
</body>
```

Now you want to modify your div content with such a string :

```
var mySpan = "<span class=\"myClass\">" + "myCustomText" + "</span>";
```

Do to that use JQuery and js like that :

```
var oldLabel = $("#myId");
var labelBody = oldLabel.parent();
oldLabel.remove ();
labelBody.append("<div id=\"myId\">" + mySpan + "</div>");
```

Comment: Are the `\\` characters actually part of the string, or did you include them here for formatting reasons?

Comment: you use innerHTML to display your string?

Comment: No these caracter are not in the code but if I don't write them on the forum the span tag dont appear

Comment: I have tryed with jquery and parserHTML() but it return me a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clean way to convert a string to elements, but you can do it by creating a new element and setting its innerHTML to your string:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = 'Les connecteurs enfichables DOIVENT être <\span class="barre"> équipé de<\/span>detrompeur.'
div.childNodes
// NodeList [ #text "Les connecteurs enfichables DOIVENT être ", <span.barre>, #text "detrompeur." ]
```